# Status of Kubernetes federation v2

Tags: kubernetes, federation

Does anyone know the status of Kubernetes federation v2? I mean which of the goals specified in the "Cluster Federation v2 API Structure and Workflow
" document are already addressed and which are not? In particular, I would like to know if policy-based resource placement is already supported?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's still pretty much a WIP. I believe you can find most of the information in their [community page](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/tree/master/sig-multicluster)

I would strongly suggest going through their [meeting notes](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1v-Kb1pUs3ww_x0MiKtgcyTXCAuZlbVlz4_A9wS3_HXY/edit) and their [recordings](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL69nYSiGNLP3iKP5EzMbtNT2zOZv6RCrX&disable_polymer=true). Also, if you have any specific questions feel free to join the meetings.

Update: There are newer projects addressing the same problem. For example:

- [Karmada](https://karmada.io/)